# Покажите пожалуйста как сделать этот фрагмен в HTML и CSS

Tags: html, css

У меня не получаеться сделать этот фрагмент. Я всё делаю через грид так что это тоже хотел сделать так, но что то не выходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что у меня получилось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Покажите пожалуйста как мне сделать это чтобы было как надо.

Comment: По-моему такое нужно делать не через grid, а через display: inline-block (ну или хотя бы через flex, если хочется стильно-модно-молодёжно)

Comment: А вообще приложите к вопросу код имеющегося решения (кнопочка «Фрагмент кода» в редакторе) чтобы отвечающим было от чего отталкиваться

Comment: В этом и минус в универе, мне показали что грид очень практичный и я соглашусь, но вот в таких ситуациях трудновато им пользоваться, возможно надо было использовать grid-template-areas

Comment: Flex стильно и молодежно, интересно почему, разве щас не пользуются больше гридом, чтобы потом не осваивать Bootstrap, который кстати я так и не могу понять

Comment: Инструменты нужно использовать не по модности, а по уместности применения. Если гриды подходят плохо — значит не нужно пытаться их вкорячить и стоит взять флексы (да и старческий inline-block тоже сработает вполне неплохо). Ну а Bootstrap тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: Так ведь используя грид потом можно проще сделать адаптивную страницу под все экраны

Comment: По словам учителя, грид это убийца bootstrap

Comment: Только вот показанная вами картинка не имеет никакого отношения ни к гридам, ни к адаптивности, ни к убийству кого-либо. Инструменты нужно подбирать по задаче, а не по моде. Пистолет тоже в чём-то лучше ножа, но вы же не режете хлеб пистолетом?

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, учту в будущем

Comment: flex уже лет 5 как не то что там модно-стильно, а просто удобно, меньше кода и больше гибкости.

Comment: Возможно, я особо не в курсе этого, я просто тренируюсь и делаю шаблоны, возможно в будущем пригодится

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант на flex.

```css
.category-block-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.category-block {
  display: block;
  background-color: #1a1716;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-blocks">
<div class="category-block-flex">
    <div class="category-block">
        часы
    </div>
    <div class="category-block">
        браслеты
    </div>
    <div class="category-block">
        ремни
    </div>
</div>
<div class="category-block-flex">
    <div class="category-block">
        ювелирные изделия
    </div>
    <div class="category-block">
        запонки
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0):

Вот так правильнее, по ширине согласно макета:

```css
.category-block-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width:380px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.category-block {
  background-color: #1a1716;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-blocks">
<div class="category-block-flex">
    <div class="category-block">
        часы
    </div>
    <div class="category-block">
        браслеты
    </div>
    <div class="category-block">
        ремни
    </div>
    <div class="category-block">
        ювелирные изделия
    </div>
    <div class="category-block">
        запонки
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я флекс почти не использовал так что это что новое